# Request.QueryString ничего не возвращает, хотя в адресной строке всё в порядке

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net

```
string CountryID = Request.QueryString["COUNTRYID"];
comm = "SELECT * FROM Country WHERE COUNTRYID = " + CountryID;

SqlCommand GetComm = new SqlCommand(comm, connect);
SqlDataReader read = GetComm.ExecuteReader();
```

`comm` получается равным `"SELECT * FROM Country WHERE COUNTRYID = "`, `CountryID` не передаётся туда.
Ссылка со значениями в порядке.

Я не понимаю, что не так...

Comment: ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ, ЕСЛИ ЗАПУСКАТЬ ЛЮБУЮ ДРУГУЮ СТРАНИЦУ!!!
Я стартовал с целевой сраницы (country.aspx) и она не запускаясь начинала дебаг с сообщения об ошибке (и в VS и в браузере), если запускать любую другую страницу (например , наполненную только словом "test" content.aspx), то всё рабоает как надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема явно не в том коде, который Вы предоставили в вопросе. Попробуйте в дебаге посмотреть значение QueryString, скорее всего параметр "COUNTRYID" там отсутствует (а может называется по другому) и причина именно в этом.

Comment: Значение QueryString?? Это как?
Я в дебаге навёл курсор на него, там вылезли всякие меню... много вложенных меню... наверное, вы про это. Действительно, там я не нашёл ни одного пункта, который бы назывался "COUNTRYID"...

Может ли это быть потому что сама цифра, которая должна передаваться, в БД хранится как int, а здесь как string? Я думал нет, потому что там ссылка read[0].ToString() - я думал это переводит в string
вот строка цикла, который формирует меню (ссылки которого и не работают):

"<a href='Country.aspx?id=" + read[0].ToString() + "'>" + read[1].ToString() + "</a>";

Comment: Посмотрите в Keys, имеется ли там такой ключ как COUNTRYID

Comment: Так у Вас там id, а не COUNTRYID

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте вот так:

```
comm = "SELECT * FROM Country WHERE COUNTRYID = @countryId"
GetComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("countryId", Id);
```

Comment: Спасибо, доберусь до компьютера попробую.

Comment: Мне кажется, проблема не в этом.

Comment: Не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать

```
String.Format( "SELECT * FROM Country WHERE COUNTRYID = {0}", CountryID)
```

Кстати, раз уж разговор на эту тему зашёл, не забывайте что в c# строка это класс, и несколько иначе работать приходится чем в Delphi (к примеру).

```
comm = "SELECT * FROM Country WHERE COUNTRYID = " + CountryID;
```

На самом деле это выражение создает новый экземпляр класса sting. Эта особенность может сыграть злую шутку когда будете работать с большими строками или же с частыми итерациями в цикле. В этом случае может помочь использование [String Builder-а](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, доберусь до компьютера попробую.

Comment: Не получилось.

Comment: Тогда однозначно проблема не в этом. Вам посоветовали несколько проверенных методов.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте соответствие адресной строки коду. Может, у Вас там COUNTRYID по-другому записано.

Comment: Спасибо. Там всё правильно.

Answer (score 1):

> comm = "SELECT * FROM Country WHERE
>   COUNTRYID = " + CountryID

[Инъекций](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) не боитесь?! 
Делайте так как написали вам [выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166558#166611).

Answer (score 0):

Наблюдал то же самое. При отладке запроса по адресу

```
https://localhost:44307/?foo=bar
```

и перенаправлении в Application_Error через Server.Transfer на страницу default.aspx, в отладчике следующие значения:

```
Request.Params["foo"] == null
Request.QueryString.Count == 0
// но:
Request.RawUrl == "/?foo=bar"
Request.Url.Query == "?foo=bar"
```

Если же адрес задан без необходимости перенаправления:

```
https://localhost:44307/default.aspx?foo=bar
```

тогда с Request.Params все в порядке.
Я решил проблему так:

```
NameValueCollection c = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
// дальше использую c["foo"]
```